# Laravel Livewire component offset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to get some technicians data trough a laravel controller called inside `Livewire`component. In some cases, controller returns `null` cause there is no technicians asociated.

Here is my livewire component rendering a view:

```
class TechniciansAssociated extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        $technicians = (new HomeController())->getTechnicians();

        return view('livewire.dashboard.technicians-associated', [
            'technicians' => $technicians,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here function called from home controller:

```
public function getTechnicians()
{
    $customer_ids = json_decode(User::find(Auth::id())->userCustomers->customer_id,true);

    $technicians_data = DB::connection('mysql')
        -> select('SELECT distinct users.id, users.name, users.surname, users.lastname, users.email, users.cargo, users.photo
           FROM users
           INNER JOIN contractsproductsmulti AS cpm ON users.id = cpm.userId
           INNER JOIN contractsproducts AS cp ON cp.id = cpm.contractproduct_id
           INNER JOIN contracts AS cont ON cont.id = cp.idcontract
           WHERE users.isActive = 1 AND cont.idCustomer IN (?)', $customer_ids
        );

    if (count($technicians_data) > 0){
        return $technicians_data;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Finally when trying to get main view where render livewire view I've got the error

```
@section('content')

<section id="dash-cust-info">
    <div class="row p-t-30 p-b-30">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Customer info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Comm_1</h4>
            <div class="card no-border no-margin">
                @livewire('dashboard.commercials-associated')
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Comm_2</h4>
            <div class="card no-border no-margin">
                @livewire('dashboard.technicians-associated')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
....
```

The error:

```
Undefined offset: 1 (View: /......../resources/views/home.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, LiveWire component needs a HTML element before get results on it's own view. E.g:

```
<div> //missed on my code
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {{$user->id}}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406932/10804409)** provide good explanation for this kind of issue in livewire. Leaving it here, So that anyone having this kind of issue in future will get help. You are welcome