# Livewire Not Rerendering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I do not know what I am missing but I followed every step but it does not rerender the view.

Here's my livewire component class:

```
use Livewire\Component;

class HelloWorld extends Component
{
    public $message = 'Hello, world!';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hello-world');
    }
}
```

Here's the livewire view:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="message">{{ $message }}
```

When I type in the input box, I see XHR requests being sent but the view does not update. What am I missing here? I have been looking around for answers for few hours already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Livewire component not refreshing/reloading automatically after refreshing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395647/laravel-livewire-component-not-refreshing-reloading-automatically-after-refreshi)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From Livewire's docs:

> Make sure your Blade view only has ONE root element.
> [Source](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#returning-blade)

Putting it in a div should fix this issue.

Comment: It's a really helpful answer for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your blade view must have only one root element and it should looks like below :

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="message">{{ $message }}
</div>
```