# livewire does not update variable after xhr

Tags: laravel, data-binding, laravel-livewire

**Description:**
the 2 way data binding does not work, the value of the variable doesn't update.

**Exact steps to reproduce**

- clean laravel installtaion
- livewire install
- livewire:make test

**Stripped-down, copy-pastable code snippets**

- livewire/Test.php

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    class Test extends Component
    {
        public $text;
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.test');
        }
    }
```

- livewire/test.blade.php

```php
    <input type="text" wire:model="text">
    {{$text}}
```

- welcome.blade.php

```php
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
            <title>Laravel</title>
    
            <!-- Fonts -->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <livewire:styles />
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: 'Nunito';
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body class="antialiased">
            <livewire:test/>
            <livewire:scripts />
        </body>
    </html>
```

- Request Ppayload

```json
    {fingerprint: {id: "p2OSso56TqMjMT4XN4Oo", name: "test", locale: "en"},…}
       fingerprint: {id: "p2OSso56TqMjMT4XN4Oo", name: "test", locale: "en"}
          id: "p2OSso56TqMjMT4XN4Oo"
          locale: "en"
          name: "test"
       serverMemo: {children: [], errors: [], htmlHash: "b6eb143a", data: {text: "te"}, dataMeta: [],…}
          checksum: "1949b7cded0c349a39cb3f8d9d36a92bd88d5c3a1b676544851ddd229d157c4c"
          children: []
          data: {text: "te"}
             text: "te"
          dataMeta: []
          errors: []
          htmlHash: "b6eb143a"
       updates: [{type: "syncInput", payload: {name: "text", value: "test"}}]
          0: {type: "syncInput", payload: {name: "text", value: "test"}}
          payload: {name: "text", value: "test"}
             name: "text"
             value: "test"
             type: "syncInput"
```

**Context**

- Livewire version: 2.2
- Laravel version: 8.10
- Browser: [Edge, Chrome, Opera]

Comment: what error your getting .?

Comment: no error appears...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Livewire component not refreshing/reloading automatically after refreshing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395647/laravel-livewire-component-not-refreshing-reloading-automatically-after-refreshi)

Comment: You need a single root element in your component's blade. You now have two, one text and one input. Wrap them in a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

As already written by [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel) your `test.blade.php` must only have one single root element like this

```php
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="text">
    {{$text}}
</div>
```