# Laravel 8 with livewire version 2, wire:model="name" not working

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 8 with Livewire version 2. but when I create `wire:model="name"` i cannot received `$name` variable value in my component

blade.php

```
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">

    Hi! My name is {{ $name }}
</div>
```

comment.php

```
class Comment extends Component
{
    public $name;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.comment');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Livewire component not refreshing/reloading automatically after refreshing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395647/laravel-livewire-component-not-refreshing-reloading-automatically-after-refreshi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resolved, I was using 2 divs. forgot that it should use only 1 root Element

Comment: I think I am stuck here too